# for-loop is neglecting several indices in an ArrayList dataset

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

In the snippet of code below, I am attempting to write the contents of the `stocks2` ArrayList into the `stock_train.csv` file. I am employing a for-loop which should loop through every element of the `stocks2` ArrayList (the debugger indicates that the size of the `stocks2` ArrayList is 2955).

However, I am tracking how many lines of data are actually getting written to the file with the variable `r`. At the end of the for-loop's runtime, `r`'s value is only 390. I have reviewed this code thoroughly and am struggling to find the issue as to why more than 80% of my data is not getting allocated to the file. (My `stock_train.csv` file only shows 390 lines of data, rather than 2955). Are there any memory allocation or syntax issues that are preventing this for-loop from writing all of `stock2`'s data to the csv file? Thanks in advance for your time.

```
    CSVWriter cd = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("src/in/stock_train.csv"), ',', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
    int r=0;
    int dd=0; // Tracker variables

    for(int g=0; g<stocks2.size(); g++) {
        Stock q = stocks2.get(g); // stocks2: size = 2955
        String[] temp2 = new String[4];
        if(q.getTimestamp().startsWith("a")) {
            dd++; // dd: 1
            break; // This code is included to neglect any data whose timestamp begins with 'a'. As evidenced by the value of 'dd', it only happens once.
        }

        temp2[0] = q.getTimestamp();
        temp2[1] = Double.toString(q.getPrice());
        temp2[2] = Double.toString(q.getVWAP(pv,v));
        temp2[3] = Integer.toString(q.getStatus()); // Data I want allocated to the "stocks_train.csv" file
        r++; // r: 390

        System.out.println(g + " " + temp2);
        cd.writeNext(temp2);
    }

    cd.close();

    /* Comments depict values of variables after the for-loops run-time based on debugger information */
```

Comment: @Turing85: I believe you nailed it right there.  He needs `continue`, not `break`.  Make an answer with that and I'll upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment suggests that you want to **skip** an entry, if the corresponding `timestamp` starts with an `"a"`. You actually use the `break;` keyword, which **terminates the loop**. This also explains why `dd` has a value of exactly `1`.

What you want is a `continue;` instead of the `break;`. This has the effect that program execution continues with the next iteration of the loop.